# Computationally efficient way of removing an entry from list without changing the order?

Tags: python, list

I have two list that are connected together. In the first one I store questions and in the second one I store answers.

If I deem a question or an answer unacceptable, I would like to remove both, keeping the order unchanged.

This is an example:

```
Questions    : Answers
0 Hi how..   : 0 answer0
1 What are.. : 1 answer1
2 What is    : 2 answer2
.................(The list will be VERY big)
```

I want to remove for example entry 1 in both lists, while keeping the order the same. How can I do so?

Comment: Wouldn't a dictionary be better for this purpose than keeping two lists that might or might not be synchronized?

Comment: And, such a dictionary can be easily created with `d(zip(questions, answers))`.

Comment: (Prior to Python 3.7, you would want to use an `OrderedDict` so that you can iterate over the questions (the keys) in their original order.)

Comment: Or, if you have no need of the actual mapping, just use the single list of pairs you get from `zip(questions, answers)` to keep them together.

Answer (score 4):

The most computationally efficient would be to replace the values in both lists with `None`, instead of removing the items.
This avoids a re-copy of all the elements on the right of the ones to discard, each time you need to discard one.

Then a simple `if element is not None` test prior to displaying or using the elements of the lists would suffice.

The order is maintained; the time complexity is `O(1)`, and you get to keep the questions and answers at the same index value as when you created them.

**Alternatively**, you could use a dictionary `{question: answer}` that could be created from the two lists, using `zip` and a dictionary comprehension, as suggested by @MrT, and @Chepner in the comments

Comment: To parse through the list with `for entry in list` then i'll just need to check if the entry is not `None` correct?